# How to convert object based on keys in JavaScipt?

Tags: javascript, function, object, converters

I have object with following format. I'm getting this object after processing some data and keys have retrieve from above mentioned data. These keys refers a data structure and that has been represented using "." full stop. I'm looking for a way that I can change this object in to the second object structure as it will easier for me to save this data in the back-end.

```
    {
   "pageId":"6103a64eaa0f0228d5487d8d",
   "answer":{
      "PremiumServices:AmazonPrime":"1",
      "paymentMethod:Paypal:PaypalUsageCode":[
         "2"
      ],
      "PaymentsToIncurCode":[
         "1",
         "2"
      ],
      "null":[
         "10",
         "4",
         "7"
      ],
      "paymentMethod:mobileWalletCodes":[
         "10"
      ],
      "paymentMethod:mobileWalletCodes.0":[
         "17"
      ],
      "paymentMethod:mobileWalletCodes.1":[
         "17"
      ],
      "paymentMethod:mobileWalletCodes.2":[
         "16"
      ],
      "paymentMethod:mobileWalletCodes.3":[
         "16"
      ]
   }
},
```

I want to convert it to below format.

```
{
  "pageId": "6103a64eaa0f0228d5487d8d",
  "answer": {
    "PremiumServices": {
      "AmazonPrime": "1"
    },
    "paymentMethod": {
      "mobileWalletCodes": {
        "0": [
          "17"
        ],
        "1": [
          "17"
        ],
        "2": [
          "16"
        ],
        "3": [
          "16"
        ]
      }
    },
    "PaymentsToIncurCode": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ],
    "PaymentsToIncuCode": [
      "10",
      "4",
      "7"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a library or function that I can convert the first object to the format of second object?

Comment: JSON is a text format. If you have the first snippet as a string, then it's JSON, and you need to parse it, at which point it is an object, and you can transform it. [There is no such thing as a JSON Object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: Yes, Javascript can convert from the first object to the second object, but looking at your input and expected output, there appears to be no concrete logic of how you come to the output, so I would say there is likely no specific function ready made for such a task.

Comment: @SathyaDev93 ... Looking at the source data and the requirements it actually also was more concise to transform into a `paymentMethod` (sub) target structure like `"paymentMethod": { "mobileWalletCodes": ["17", "17", "16", "16"] }`

Comment: @SathyaDev93 ... There is also no `"paymentMethod": { "Paypal": { ... } }` target. Is this intended or just forgotten?

Comment: @SathyaDev93 ... Where is the connection/relation/common sense in leaving `"PaymentsToIncurCode": ["1", "2"]` untouched but mapping `"null": ["10", "4", "7"]` into `"PaymentsToIncuCode": ["10", "4", "7"]`, and what is the real world difference in between `PaymentsToIncurCode` and `PaymentsToIncuCode`, here it is just one random character less. Is this too, all intentional? Then the OP has to go with **jabaa**'s approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple custom conversion steps for the properties. This is the most generic approach I was able to achieve:

```js
const json = `{
   "pageId":"6103a64eaa0f0228d5487d8d",
   "answer":{
      "PremiumServices:AmazonPrime":"1",
      "paymentMethod:Paypal:PaypalUsageCode":[
         "2"
      ],
      "PaymentsToIncurCode":[
         "1",
         "2"
      ],
      "null":[
         "10",
         "4",
         "7"
      ],
      "paymentMethod:mobileWalletCodes":[
         "10"
      ],
      "paymentMethod:mobileWalletCodes.0":[
         "17"
      ],
      "paymentMethod:mobileWalletCodes.1":[
         "17"
      ],
      "paymentMethod:mobileWalletCodes.2":[
         "16"
      ],
      "paymentMethod:mobileWalletCodes.3":[
         "16"
      ]
   }
}`;
const data = JSON.parse(json);

const result = {
  pageId: data.pageId,
  answer: {
    PremiumServices: Object
      .fromEntries(Object
        .entries(data.answer)
        .filter(([key]) =>
          key.startsWith('PremiumServices')
        ).map(([key, value]) =>
          [key.split(':')[1], value]
        )
      ),
    paymentMethod: Object
      .fromEntries(Object
        .entries(data.answer)
        .filter(([key]) =>
          key.startsWith('paymentMethod:mobileWalletCodes.')
        ).map(([key, value]) =>
          [key.split('.')[1], value]
        )
      ),
    PaymentsToIncurCode: data.answer.PaymentsToIncurCode,
    PaymentsToIncuCode: data.answer.null
  }
};
console.log(result);

const resultJson = JSON.stringify(result);

console.log(resultJson);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a functional recursive approach using [ramda](https://ramdajs.com/)

```
const convertObjectStructure = R.compose(
  R.reduce(R.mergeDeepWith((x, y) => R.is(Object, x) && R.is(Array, y) ? x : R.is(Object, y) && R.is(Array, x) ? y : R.concat(x, y)), {}),
  R.map(([k, v]) => R.assocPath(R.split(/\.|:/, k), R.when(R.both(R.is(Object), R.compose(R.complement, R.is)(Array)), convertObjectStructure)(v), {})),
  R.toPairs
)

convertObjectStructure(JSON.parse(json))
```

Not so clean as I would wish, but it's already midnight.

See it in [playground](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?const%20json%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%22pageId%22%3A%226103a64eaa0f0228d5487d8d%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%22answer%22%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22PremiumServices%3AAmazonPrime%22%3A%221%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22paymentMethod%3APaypal%3APaypalUsageCode%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%222%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22PaymentsToIncurCode%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%221%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%222%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22null%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2210%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%224%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%227%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22paymentMethod%3AmobileWalletCodes%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2210%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22paymentMethod%3AmobileWalletCodes.0%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2217%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22paymentMethod%3AmobileWalletCodes.1%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2217%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22paymentMethod%3AmobileWalletCodes.2%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2216%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22paymentMethod%3AmobileWalletCodes.3%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2216%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20convertObjectStructure%20%3D%20R.compose%28%0A%20%20R.reduce%28R.mergeDeepWith%28%28x%2C%20y%29%20%3D%3E%20R.is%28Object%2C%20x%29%20%26%26%20R.is%28Array%2C%20y%29%20%3F%20x%20%3A%20R.is%28Object%2C%20y%29%20%26%26%20R.is%28Array%2C%20x%29%20%3F%20y%20%3A%20R.concat%28x%2C%20y%29%29%2C%20%7B%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20R.map%28%28%5Bk%2C%20v%5D%29%20%3D%3E%20R.assocPath%28R.split%28%2F%5C.%7C%3A%2F%2C%20k%29%2C%20R.when%28R.both%28R.is%28Object%29%2C%20R.compose%28R.complement%2C%20R.is%29%28Array%29%29%2C%20convertObjectStructure%29%28v%29%2C%20%7B%7D%29%29%2C%0A%20%20R.toPairs%0A%29%0A%0AconvertObjectStructure%28json%29%0A%0A)

**Update #1**

> The output is not the sames as the OP's.. –
> Keith

```
const renameKeysDeep = R.curry((mapping, input) => R.compose(
  R.reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    if (!(k in mapping)) return {...acc, [k]: v};
    if (R.is(Object)(mapping[k])) return {...acc, [k]: renameKeysDeep(mapping[k], v)};
    return {...acc, [mapping[k]]: v};
  }, {}),
  R.toPairs
)(input))

const convertObjectStructure = R.compose(
  R.reduce(R.mergeDeepWith((x, y) => R.is(Object, x) && R.is(Array, y) ? x : R.is(Object, y) && R.is(Array, x) ? y : R.concat(x, y)), {}),
  R.map(([k, v]) => R.assocPath(R.split(/\.|:/, k), R.when(R.both(R.is(Object), R.compose(R.complement, R.is)(Array)), convertObjectStructure)(v), {})),
  R.toPairs
)

// Usage
R.compose(
  convertObjectStructure,
  renameKeysDeep({'answer': {'null': 'PaymentsToIncuCode'}}),
  R.dissocPath(['answer', 'paymentMethod:Paypal:PaypalUsageCode']),
)(JSON.parse(json))
```

See it in [playground](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?const%20json%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%22pageId%22%3A%226103a64eaa0f0228d5487d8d%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%22answer%22%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22PremiumServices%3AAmazonPrime%22%3A%221%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22paymentMethod%3APaypal%3APaypalUsageCode%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%222%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22PaymentsToIncurCode%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%221%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%222%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22null%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2210%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%224%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%227%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22paymentMethod%3AmobileWalletCodes%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2210%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22paymentMethod%3AmobileWalletCodes.0%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2217%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22paymentMethod%3AmobileWalletCodes.1%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2217%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22paymentMethod%3AmobileWalletCodes.2%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2216%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22paymentMethod%3AmobileWalletCodes.3%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2216%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20renameKeysDeep%20%3D%20R.curry%28%28mapping%2C%20input%29%20%3D%3E%20R.compose%28%0A%20%20R.reduce%28%28acc%2C%20%5Bk%2C%20v%5D%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28%21%28k%20in%20mapping%29%29%20return%20%7B...acc%2C%20%5Bk%5D%3A%20v%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28R.is%28Object%29%28mapping%5Bk%5D%29%29%20return%20%7B...acc%2C%20%5Bk%5D%3A%20renameKeysDeep%28mapping%5Bk%5D%2C%20v%29%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B...acc%2C%20%5Bmapping%5Bk%5D%5D%3A%20v%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20R.toPairs%0A%29%28input%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20convertObjectStructure%20%3D%20R.compose%28%0A%20%20R.reduce%28R.mergeDeepWith%28%28x%2C%20y%29%20%3D%3E%20R.is%28Object%2C%20x%29%20%26%26%20R.is%28Array%2C%20y%29%20%3F%20x%20%3A%20R.is%28Object%2C%20y%29%20%26%26%20R.is%28Array%2C%20x%29%20%3F%20y%20%3A%20R.concat%28x%2C%20y%29%29%2C%20%7B%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20R.map%28%28%5Bk%2C%20v%5D%29%20%3D%3E%20R.assocPath%28R.split%28%2F%5C.%7C%3A%2F%2C%20k%29%2C%20R.when%28R.both%28R.is%28Object%29%2C%20R.compose%28R.complement%2C%20R.is%29%28Array%29%29%2C%20convertObjectStructure%29%28v%29%2C%20%7B%7D%29%29%2C%0A%20%20R.toPairs%0A%29%0A%0AR.compose%28%0A%20%20convertObjectStructure%2C%0A%20%20renameKeysDeep%28%7B%27answer%27%3A%20%7B%27null%27%3A%20%27PaymentsToIncuCode%27%7D%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20R.dissocPath%28%5B%27answer%27%2C%20%27paymentMethod%3APaypal%3APaypalUsageCode%27%5D%29%2C%0A%29%28json%29%0A%0A)

Comment: it's not the same as in question because:       `"null":["10", "4", "7"],` does not make sens to be converted to `"PaymentsToIncuCode": ["10", "4", "7"]` (without hardcoding precise mapping), and my solution is more generic and recursive, so does not matter what is the input it will handle any.

Comment: Okay @Keith I made it complex now )) see `Update #1`

Answer (score -2):

Finally I found a best solution for my problem. [Dot-Object](https://github.com/rhalff/dot-object) makes it possible to transform JavaScript objects using dot notation.

```
var dot = require('dot-object');

var row = {
  'id': 2,
  'contact.name.first': 'John',
  'contact.name.last': 'Doe',
  'contact.email': 'example@gmail.com',
  'contact.info.about.me': 'classified',
  'devices[0]': 'mobile',
  'devices[1]': 'laptop',
  'some.other.things.0': 'this',
  'some.other.things.1': 'that'
};

dot.object(row);

console.log(row);
// result will be as below
{
  "id": 2,
  "contact": {
    "name": {
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Doe"
    },
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "info": {
      "about": {
        "me": "classified"
      }
    }
  },
  "devices": [
    "mobile",
    "laptop"
  ],
  "some": {
    "other": {
      "things": [
        "this",
        "that"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```